# Push new key element into subdocument of mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a mongo collection with the following structure:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
   history : {

   }
}
```

Now I have to update such collection pushing into `history` subdocument new associative object so it should look like:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
   history : {
        "06/04/2015" : {}
   }
}
```

What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: It's considered bad design practice in MongoDB to use dynamic values as keys in documents, it becomes pretty difficult to update.

Comment: @chridam So better is to make `history` - array and use `$push` ?

Comment: Absolutely correct but then again that depends on how often the information will change or how often it's read. If history is updated regularly, then normalizing it will be a good idea. If it's changes infrequently then there is little benefit to optimise the update process at the expense of every read your application performs.

Comment: FWIW, the goal of an "history" is to get back data by date range, most of the time (say "data for june 2014"). This will not be that easy with your initial design.

Comment: @chridam but with such design it would be hard to get history for exact date. btw, history items dont change after inserting. The only operation - appending new history item and searching by exact date.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux So i can make `history` as array and each item inside should contain datetime. And I can make an index on this datetime field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that data-format:

```
> db.test.insert({_id: oid, history: {} })
```

It is pretty easy to add a new *field* in the embedded document `history`. You just need the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) update operator and you will have to use [dot-notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to specify the field:

```
> db.test.update({_id:oid},{$set: { "history.06/04/2015": "6 of june"}}) 
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Producing:

```
> db.test.find({_id:oid},{_id:0})
{ "history" : { "06/04/2015" : "6 of june" } }
```

Please note the `$set` operation is [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence):

```
> db.test.update({_id:oid},{$set: { "history.06/04/2015": "6 of june"}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
> db.test.find({_id:oid},{_id:0})
{ "history" : { "06/04/2015" : "6 of june" } }
```

---

That being said, as explained in comments, this is probably *not* the best way to store history. Just to mention that, it will prevent proper indexing of your history by date, for example.

In fact, there are *many* different ways to store your history data. Just *few* examples. All of them have (probably) pros and (definitively) cons:

```
{
  history: [
    { "06/04/2015": "6 of June" },
  ]
}
```

```
{
  history: {
    "2015" : [
      { "06/04": "6 of June" },
    ]
  }
}
```

```
{
  history: {
    {
      year: "2015";
      data: [
        { "06/04": "6 of June" },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

etc.

---

<sub>BTW, using a proper date object is probably better than using a string to store date. I use that later here only to avoid making the examples more cumbersome.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

change your schema (lets call it 'Collection' for this example):

```
{
   _id : ObjectId,
    history : [{
   date: *some date*
   data: {*data data data data*}
  }]
}
```

and then push to the history array objects that contain two keys, the first being date whose value is the string "mm/dd/yyyy" and then the second is data whose value is the data object associated with that date.

now when you want to add a subdoc of

```
{date: "05/01/1944",
 data: {
   event: "foo",
   duration: "bar"
}
```

to a doc with

```
{
  _id: {$oid: 1},
 history: []
}
```

all you do is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
var collections = mongoose.model('Collection');
var id = *_id of what you want to add to, in this case "1"*;
var change =  {date: "05/01/1944",
 data: {
   event: "foo",
   duration: "bar"
}

collections.update({
  _id: new ObjectId(id)
}, {$push:{history: change}});
```